# Lebesgue Integral Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The notes I am reading states the monotone convergence theorem as follows (for a measure space $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$:

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of positive measurable functions such that $f_{n+1}\geq f_n$ a.e. for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f= \limsup_{n \to \infty}f_n$. Then $\mu(f_n)\uparrow \mu(f)\leq\infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

The proof first handles the case that $f_{n+1}\geq f_n$ everywhere. The proof continues by stating that $f(s)=\lim f_n(s)$ for all $s \in S,$ possibly with value $\infty.$ After dealing with this case, they handle the a.e. case by considering that $\mu(f_n)=\mu(f_n1_{N^c})$ and $\mu(f)=\mu(f1_{N^c})$ and applying the previous case, where $N=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}N_n $ for $N_n=\{f_n>f_{n+1}\}$ .

My question is, with the convention that $f(s)=\lim f_n(s)$ can take on the value $\infty$, why do they write $f= \limsup_{n \to \infty}f_n$ instead of $f=\lim_{n\to \infty}f$?

Comment: Because $f_{n+1}\geq f_n\ almost\  everywhere$. There may indeed be $x\in S$ for which the sequence is not increasing.

Comment: @ChilangoIncomprendido and for all other $x\in N^c$ we simply have $\limsup f_n=\lim f_n$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.